# How to get JSON value from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

here i get my remote server response(JSON) to convert in NSDictionary like this approach.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog (@"%@",dictionary);
```

i got my output text below:

output:

```
{
            "city" = "";
            "state" = "";
            "zip" = "";
            "address" = 0;
            "id" = 1;
            "name" = "test name";
            "country_name" = 0;
            email = 0;
            "fax" = 0;
            "mobile" = 0;
            phone = 1234567890;
            website = "";
        }
```

if i used to get name variable from the NSDictionary . i got expection this

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcada210

-(void)addAccountDatails:(NSDictionary *)accArray{

        NSLog(@"- %@",[accArray objectForKey:@"name"]);
    }
```

how to i get the name value in NSDictionary

Comment: Post your correct response. Seems to be incorrect. dictionary with dictionary but first dictionary haven't key.

Comment: i edited my question please revoted for me. i read stackoverflow doc for how to ask question,how to post answer,comment etc., but i can't to create new question please help me

Comment: i can't to create new question please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

for(NSDictionary *dict in array)
{
    NSLog(@"Name = %@", [dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `NSDictionary` to `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
[self addAccountDatails:array];

-(void)addAccountDatails:(NSArray *)accArray {    
    NSLog(@"- %@",[(NSDictionary*)accArray[0] objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

Comment: Is this correct? Where did you see array?

Comment: Here: `-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcada210`